# Oracle Database 19c Trigger issue

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

I am using Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition 19 19.0.0.0.0.

I would like to create a trigger that always sets the 1st letter in a column to capitalized.

```
   create or replace TRIGGER TRIGGER_NAME
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF COLUMN_NAME ON TABLE_NAME
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
   :NEW.COLUMN_NAME := upper(substr(:NEW.COLUMN_NAME,1,1))||substr(:NEW.COLUMN_NAME,2);
   END;
```

The trigger is created, but **I get an ORA-00900: Invalid SQL statement error**.

Why and what does the solution look like?

Comment: This seems to work for me when I created a stub-y `table_name`. Can you share a [mcve] please?

Comment: yes, you've already done right, just a simple table in another oracle database works this code.

Comment: There is no SQL statement in your trigger, so perhaps the issue is in the insert or update statement you are trying to run?

Comment: no, I get the error from the trigger, not from any insert or update statement. This comes from system that i can 100% trust. Without the trigger all works fine.

Comment: I'm facing 0RA-00900 error in my SELECT query in oracle 19c, but the same query works completely fine in 12c. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I couldn't solve the error, I decided to use a solution outside the database.

Answer (score 1):

To capitalize the first letter in a string you can use regexp

```
SELECT
regexp_replace ('string', '[a-z]', upper (substr ('string', 1, 1)), 1, 1, 'i')
FROM dual;
```

This assumes that the first letter is the one you want to convert. It your input text starts with a number, such as 2 strings then it won't change it to 2 Strings.

Comment: @Fedor v. R. Why dont you provide the create table and trigger statement along with an INSERT and update statement and we can provide you an answer. Edit your original question to include this information. Several solutions have been offered and you haven't acknowledged any

Comment: I couldn't solve the error, I decided to use a solution outside the database.

Answer (score 1):

Using INITCAP will achieve this:

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRIGGER_NAME
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF COLUMN_NAME ON TABLE_NAME
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
:NEW.COLUMN_NAME := INITCAP(:NEW.COLUMN_NAME);
END;
```

Comment: I couldn't solve the error, I decided to use a solution outside the database.